# PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I keep getting this error and I don't know how to fix it. When I type in the shell `mysql -u root -p` and type the password, I can log in to mysql. The strange thing is that, I can log in without password too. If I open my project in the browser, I get this error. I tried the parameters_test.yml with and without password, still not working. It just writes: `PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`. It doesn't gives me the reason, the project just thinks I don't have access to the db. I have mariadb 10 installed. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Why do you edit "parameters_test.yml"? This config is only by the PHPUnit Routine. Use parameters_dev.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is strange that you can access through terminal, You have made the grant?

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'; // For root without password            
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Your_Password'; // For root with password
```